# API.AI with google assistant - phone number capture problems

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

We are trying to capture a phone number. Actually many other numbers, like amounts, zip, etc. We are using Google Home.

The below urls are JSON payloads we received on the fulfillment side. The entity name is TheNumber.

One JSON is when we setup the entity as @sys.number the other JSON when it was @sys.phone-number.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/xapp-bela/gh/number-test.json

https://s3.amazonaws.com/xapp-bela/gh/phone-number-test.json

The first problem is that the google assistant is really struggling to recognize number sequences, like phone numbers or zip codes. But even when it gets it right (according to the originalRequest in the JSON payload), the entity still has the wrong value when it arrives to the fulfillment side.

I guess my question is what am I doing wrong? Is anybody seeing the same problems?

Comment: We're also having issues with this. We've tried breaking numbers into chunks, different types etc. But still can't find a stable solution. Did you find anything that worked?

Comment: When was the last time you tried? A few days ago they sent me an email about fixing it. It works a lot better now.

Comment: Thanks we'll try again.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will help since this is more about talking to the Google Home device  but.... I too was having a similar issue with a long number.  If you use @sys.number-sequence as part of your Intent's context, this will allow you to recite much longer numbers without the device interrupting you.  In your NodeJS code, you can grab the argument for that number-sequence for use in your Google Home agent.

```
if (assistant.getArgument('number-sequence') != null) { <do something> }
```