# Unable to read very large number in api.ai as parameter

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am developing a customer care chat bot to resolve basic queries of customer for my e-commerce site. My order id is 13 digit long. To read queries like

> "Please check my order status with id 9876566765432"

api.ai is unable to understand that it is order id. I have set entity type `@sys.number`. It is able to identify smaller number like 343434 etc. I have tried with `@sys.number-integer`, `@sys.number-sequence` but not working for long numbers. Pleas advise...

Comment: I feel your pain. I just posted this yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356200/api-ai-with-google-assistant-phone-number-capture-problems

Comment: Can you use the @sys.any wildcard and parse the input from a backend service?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the enterprise edition you can use `@sys.number-sequence`.